Windows 10 login screen user avatar shows after geneneric placeholder. How to prevent it?
I am (actually trying to set it) using Windows 10 IOT LTS Enterprise Edition in the kiosk mode.
I have autologin enabled. During the autologin, Windows is displaying the login screen. I prefer to disable it completely - but I tried almost everything - but the screen is displayed briefly.
I have set int Settings/Accounts/Your Info/My Picture using .jpg image. This image is displayed during the autologin but for a brief moment the generic placeholder is displayed.
How to disable or replace the standard placeholder (it is a png image located in one of the WinSxS folders)?

for a fraction of a second and then it displays the correct image

Directory content:


This generic placeholder is display just once or every time the user is logged into? What version of  Windows 10 IOT LTS specifically?

Have you tried to modify the PNG files located in %ProgramData%\Microsoft\User Account Pictures

@Ramhound Problem is that this directory does not exist. (I know it is  hidden - simply no User Account Pictures. I searched for png and bmp images and only place they exist is this internal directory

You navigated to %ProgramData%\Microsoft\User Account Pictures and you were unable to do so? Because the directory exists on every version of Windows I have access to.

@Ramhound this directory is contains only ini file but not pictures. On PC I work now I have png images in this directory. It is a nightmare. Lack of consistency is unbelievable.

What if you manually create the images? Using the appropriate names user.png, user-32.png, user-40.png, user-192.png? You never address if this happens every time you log into the user or just the first time you log into the user.

Not an answer, but maybe a good suggestion? You can force windows into hibernation instead of shutdown. Given that Hybrid shutdown is basically closing all apps and then do hibernation anyway, you can skip that step and straight go into hibernation. That way, the current user remains logged in. Only downside is, that if you want to close all apps and reset to a default state at every login, that will no longer work. If you don't need that, this might be a great idea.

@LPChip most of the time it will be hibernated, but from time to time I want to restart the system.

You can always restart yourself. You will see that logon icon still briefly, but that should be okay right? Maybe that is a way to move forward.

@Ramhound I did fresh instalation and eventually I got the files. Changing them does not sort out the problem.
